# Adding a cell on the top of a dynamic UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I add a cell with a label in it in a new section on the top of the tableView as section 0 and i show and hide this section according to what type of data i'm displaying.

It works fine when there is no data in the hashtag type posts then when there is hashtag data to be displayed in the array like two or three items it works fine and the top section 0 cell is displayed then when i scroll down and up again i get an error in the `AppDelegate` after trying to return the top section cell.

I know the question is a little bit complicated but what i'm trying to achieve is to display and hide a cell on the top of my feed according to the type of data i'm displaying in my `tableview`. If hashtag news feed data then show the top cell in section 0 if showing ordinary news feed in the `tableview` then return only one section and don't load the top section with the cell inside of it.

By the way i'm displaying the cell as a Nib. And declaring it in the `viewDidLoad`

```
let reloadNib = UINib(nibName: "ReloadTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    feedTableView.register(reloadNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "reloadCell")
```

> Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x102a772a0)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell


    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        if hashPostsOnly {
            let reloadCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reloadCell", for: indexPath) as! ReloadTableViewCell
            return reloadCell  // ERROR AFTER RETURNING CELL

        } else {

            //For the protocol delegate i made
            cell.delegate = self
            cell.feed = feeds[indexPath.row]
            cell.postCommentTextView.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.cellIndexPath = indexPath
            cell.userProfilePhotoBtn.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.postMoreCommentsBtn.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.postMoreCommentsBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(moreCommentsTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

            return cell
        }
    case 1:

        //For the protocol delegate i made
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.feed = feeds[indexPath.row]
        cell.postCommentTextView.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.cellIndexPath = indexPath
        cell.userProfilePhotoBtn.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.postMoreCommentsBtn.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.postMoreCommentsBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(moreCommentsTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        return cell
    default:
        return cell
    }

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if hashPostsOnly {
        return 2
    } else {
        return 1
    }
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        if hashPostsOnly {
            return 1

        } else {
            return feeds.count
        }
    } else {
        return feeds.count
    }


}
```

Here is a screen shot of what i'm achieving but when i scroll down then up it reloads the top section cell "Reload Feeds" and then error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are just two sections and you had duplicate code, things can be simplified to:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    if indexPath.section == 0 && hashPostsOnly
    {
        let reloadCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reloadCell", for: indexPath) as! ReloadTableViewCell

        return reloadCell
    }
    else
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell

        //For the protocol delegate i made
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.feed = feeds[indexPath.row]
        cell.postCommentTextView.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.cellIndexPath = indexPath
        cell.userProfilePhotoBtn.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.postMoreCommentsBtn.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.postMoreCommentsBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(moreCommentsTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, this answer eliminates the double-dequeue. I'm pretty confident that was your problem

Answer (score 1):

I can't be 100% sure without knowing the exact error you're getting or knowing if there are other issues in the code elsewhere causing this, but:

As a general rule, dequeuing twice from a table view and returning a single cell does bad things in weird and mysterious ways. Refactor your code to only deuque a regular cell when you need it and not to do so when you're showing the refresh button